# Java if works, else doesn't with no error messages

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting the else statement to kick in.  This code is within a GUI which sends an email to the user after the username is entered in the text field.  If it is found in the SQL database, it retrieves the email address and all is good. If a username is entered in which is not in the database, it does nothing, I don't get an error message, it just hangs.  Here is the code from the submit button

```
jButtonSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
           try 
             {
             username = (jTextFieldUsername.getText());

             connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
             query = "SELECT User_userName, User_email FROM user_details WHERE " +
                     "User_userName = '"+username+"'";

             PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query);
             rs =stm.executeQuery();
             while (rs.next()) 
             {  
                String eMail = rs.getString ("User_email");

                if (username.equals(rs.getString("User_userName"))) 
                {  
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "An email with your password "
                            + "has been sent \nto " + eMail); 
                }// end if

                else 
                {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect username.  If "
                         + "you are unable to login\n"
                         + "with your current username, please contact us on\n"
                         + "info@somewhere.com.au."); 
                }//end else
            } //end while  
          close();
        }//end try  //catch statement follows
```

In anticipation thanks....

Thank you all for your help.  It works now and you have effectively solved another of my problems.  Here is the final code.  Thanks again.

```
int count = 0;
```

while(rs.next()){

```
   eMail = rs.getString ("User_email");
   count++;}

        if (count != 0) 
        {        
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "An email with your password "
                 + "has been sent \nto " + eMail); 
        }// end if

        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect username.  If "
                 + "you are unable to login\n"
                 + "with your current username, please contact us on\n"
                 + "info@somewhere.com.au."); 
        }//end else

           // } //end while
```

Comment: Look at your query! It won't return any result if you give a wrong username

Comment: Oh wow, the query is wrong, how did I miss that? So how can I get around that? and Mitch, the debugger showed no errors.

Comment: What the point of using a prepared statement if you're not going to use prepared statement format?

Comment: @Patty No, the query is right (in terms of the SQL), but your logic is wrong. The database is already responsible for checking that the username matches the row returned from the database, you don't need to do that again. You need to check if anything was returned at all in the resultset.

Comment: @Patty also, peeskillet is right - you are using PreparedStatement, which is good, but you're using it wrong, so this won't prevent the kind of security problems which PreparedStatement is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @Robin thanks,this is all new to me, hence the mistakes. So if I tried something like     if (rs.getString("User_userName").isEmpty())   it should be an error if the username is not there?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to check the equality of username in while loop because you already query with that name.

```
int count=0;
while (rs.next()) 
         {
     count++;
}

 if (count>0) 
            {  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "An email with your password "
                        + "has been sent \nto " + eMail); 
            }// end if

            else 
            {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect username.  If "
                     + "you are unable to login\n"
                     + "with your current username, please contact us on\n"
                     + "info@somewhere.com.au."); 
            }//end else
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the full code...but the ones you want!

```
query = "SELECT User_userName, User_email FROM user_details WHERE User_userName = ?";

                 PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                 stm.setString(1, username);
                 rs =stm.executeQuery();
..
..
//And to check if rs is null
if(rs!=null){
   while(rs.next()){
     ....
    }
}
else{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect username.  If "
                             + "you are unable to login\n"
                             + "with your current username, please contact us on\n"
                             + "info@somewhere.com.au."); 
}
```